# Django not loading css and JS

Tags: python, django

As the question implies, my django doesn't seem to be loading the js and css for my theme.

This is the structure of my project:

```
-->mysiteX
---->.idea
---->mysite
------->migrations
       __init__
       admin.py
       apps.py
       models.py
       test.py
       views.py
---->mysiteX
       __init__
       settings
       urls
       wsgi
----->venv
-------->Lib
---------->site-packages
----------->django
------------>contrib
------------->auth
-------------->templates
               index.html
--------------->static
---------------->js
---------------->css
---------------->img
---------------->fonts                
db.sqlite3
manage
```

This is what I have in my settings.py file

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/templates')
STATIC_URL = '/templates/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

I have tried changing my settings.py file to this effect

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/templates/static')
```

but still not getting the css and JS loaded. Here is a screenshot of my page
[image: screenshot]

Comment: You got 'TATIC_URL' or 'STATIC_URL' in settings?

Comment: @MichaelStachura typo...I have STATIC_URL

Comment: I suppose it was typo mistake but it's always better to ask :)

You got quite nested static files as I can see. I assume it is necessary due to project environment/requirements. Check what exactly your BASE_DIR and  STATIC_ROOT are and then you will be able to fix it. 
At least (not reccomended) you can set STATIC_ROOT as an absolute path.

Comment: @MichaelStachura have been trying to do that but seem to be failing

Comment: Ok as i can see in comments below it's quite old Django version. Can you upgrade it to 2.2?

Answer (score 1):

Change This Line:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

To This:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/templates/static')
```

Comment: Thanks, TATIC_URL was a typo, I actually have static_url

Comment: @Emm But in your structure there is no `gradientboostMVP` folder

Comment: sorry about that, have removed that, will update my question

Comment: @Emm Answer Updated

Comment: using this as the structure returns a template does not exist error message

Comment: @Emm Please Reset it to your default structure and try me updated answer!

Comment: Because `static` folder exist in templates folder

Comment: @Emm Can You Please Tell Me Your Django Version?

Comment: version 1.11.26. Sorry do you mind elaborating what you mean by reset it to default do you mean the structure I had when I posted the question?

Comment: @Emm You Are Using Old Version Of `Django` If You Don't mind There is `2.2` version you can try because i don't know about old version of `django`! reset means try your default structure that you add in the question!

Comment: thanks, I seem to be getting the same issue with this

Answer (score 0):

The static path (css,html,js) and is not listed on path structure appended here. Where is it located? Assuming you forgot to add it, here is the debug steps:

1) Certify that you have a /static folder on BASE_DIR

2) You should run "python manage.py collectstatic"

3) If it didn't work, press F12 (or view source code) on your browser to see where the css location was rendered.